# How can I get the calculatedfield value in DevExpress?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, calculated-field

I create a calculatedfield in the design mode and I need to obtein the value for this calculatedfield in my behind code, there is no (.text) or (.value) to obtein the value.
How can I obtein the value?

I accept suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the summary fields? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument702

Comment: Hi, can you provide your code sample because it is currently not clear which of culculatedfield do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has an eventhandler GetValue which has a Value property.
[here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUICalculatedField_GetValuetopic) is the documentation